# Reading order for Animorphs

Tags: suggested-order, animorphs

In what order should the Animorphs, Megamorphs, Chronicles, and Alternamorphs  be read?

Comment: Nice post. We need more Animorphs questions on this site!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Animorphs

Well, that's easy: they're numbered 1 to 54, after all.

### Megamorphs

The Megamorphs books tie into the main series, so they're also easy to place:

- [*The Andalite's Gift*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andalite's_Gift) takes place between book 7 and book 8
- [*In the Time of Dinosaurs*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_the_Time_of_Dinosaurs) takes place between book 18 and book 19
- *Elfangor's Secret* takes place between book 29 and book 30
- [*Back to Before*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_Before) takes place between book 40 and book 41.

### Chronicles

[*The Andalite Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andalite_Chronicles) is set before the start of the main series, and could be read before starting the latter, although personally I'd prefer to learn about the Andalites and Yeerks in the way we're originally meant to, in book 1 of the main series. This novel also contains a spoiler from book 23.

[*The Hork-Bajir Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hork-Bajir_Chronicles) are again set before the start of the main series, with surrounding narration (two Hork-Bajir to Tobias) which is set somewhere between book 13 and book 20. This surrounding text contains major spoilers from book 13, but none from any books thereafter.

[*Visser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visser_%28novel%29) is set directly after book 35, but also covers events from before the start of the series.

[*The Ellimist Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ellimist_Chronicles) is a foreshadowing of book 54, tying in to the beginning of that book despite covering events from billions of years in the past.

### Alternamorphs (NON-CANON)

Personally I wouldn't bother reading these. They're not by Applegate; they don't fit into the continuity of the series; and they're written in second-person narrative so as to be more like role-playing games than novels. However, since you asked ...

[*The First Journey*](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/The_First_Journey) is based roughly on books 1 and 11, so it should be read after at least these. [*The Next Passage*](http://animorphs.wikia.com/wiki/The_Next_Passage) is based roughly on books 20 and 26 as well as Megamorphs 2, so it should be read after at least book 26.

### Summing up...

Here's the reading order I'd suggest (books outside the main series highlighted in bold):

- 1: The Invasion
- 2: The Visitor
- 3: The Encounter
- 4: The Message
- 5: The Predator
- 6: The Capture
- 7: The Stranger
- **Megamorphs 1: The Andalite's Gift**
- 8: The Alien
- 9: The Secret
- 10: The Android
- 11: The Forgotten
- ***Alternamorphs: The First Journey either here or at the very end***
- 12: The Reaction
- 13: The Change
- **The Hork-Bajir Chronicles**
- 14: The Unknown
- 15: The Escape
- 16: The Warning
- 17: The Underground
- 18: The Decision
- **Megamorphs 2: In the Time of Dinosaurs**
- 19: The Departure
- 20: The Discovery
- 21: The Threat
- 22: The Solution
- 23: The Pretender
- **The Andalite Chronicles**
- 24: The Suspicion
- 25: The Extreme
- 26: The Attack
- ***Alternamorphs: The Next Passage either here or at the very end***
- 27: The Exposed
- 28: The Experiment
- 29: The Sickness
- **Megamorphs 3: Elfangor's Secret**
- 30: The Reunion
- 31: The Conspiracy
- 32: The Separation
- 33: The Illusion
- 34: The Prophecy
- 35: The Proposal
- **Visser**
- 36: The Mutation
- 37: The Weakness
- 38: The Arrival
- 39: The Hidden
- 40: The Other
- **Megamorphs 4: Back to Before**
- 41: The Familiar
- 42: The Journey
- 43: The Test
- 44: The Unexpected
- 45: The Revelation
- 46: The Deception
- 47: The Resistance
- 48: The Return
- 49: The Diversion
- 50: The Ultimate
- 51: The Absolute
- 52: The Sacrifice
- 53: The Answer
- **The Ellimist Chronicles**
- 54: The Beginning

Comment: It should be noted that the Ellimist Chronicles could easily be put at the very end; after all, it's a huuge sidetrack story right during the climax of the entire series, and ruins the flow just a tad.  Also is the Andalite Chronicles spoiler really necessary for a reading guide?

Comment: @Ketura Good point re the spoiler; edited.

Comment: Re Hork Bajir: it was published the same month as 23.  But, Wikipedia points out that in it Tobias is restless re no recent missions, and in 23 he comments about how he’d been very busy (due to 20-23 plot arc), and so in Wikipedia’s list it’s placed between 19 and 20 as “the last possible break point.”  Yes, that means 19 has a non-main-series book before AND after, but I think that fits better than right after 13.

Comment: I recently read through HBC and I noticed that it referenced things about yeerk physiology first said in books 16 and 19. Not especially spoilerly, but I think it'd be better to wait until closer to the release date, and either read it immediately before or after the David Trilogy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this list except for The Ellimist Chronicles - I usually read it directly before the start of the final arc (so book 49, if I recall correctly) as the books which tie up the story read more like one long book and reading TEC so near the end messes up the flow of the story for me.

Comment: If you are referring to a list provided by another answer, you ought to either explicitly link to that other answer or to imply repeat the list with your changes.  Mentioning the other answer is considered to be good form, whether their information was utilized or not.  Cheers!